# How to get all the posts from a wordpress blog using client.call function?

Tags: python, wordpress, xmlrpclib, xmlrpcclient

I am using python wordpress_xmlrpc library for extracting wordpress blog data. I want to fetch all posts of my wordpress blog. This is my code

```
client = Client(url, 'user', 'passw')
all_posts = client.call(GetPosts())
```

But this is returning only the latest 10 posts. Is there any way to get all the posts?

Comment: Haven't used the library, but the documentation says that you can pass a parameter indicating the number of posts you want: https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/methods.html?highlight=get%20post#module-wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Even if I pass any particular number, then also it returns exactly 10 posts.

Comment: How are you passing the `number` parameter?

Comment: client.call(GetPosts(<number>))

Comment: The documentation says that you have to pass it as a `dict`. I'll write it down as an answer to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/methods.html?highlight=get%20post#module-wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts), you can pass a parameter indicating how many posts you want to retrieve as:

`client.call(GetPosts({'number': 100}))`

Alternatively, if you want to get all the posts, check this out: https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/posts.html#result-paging

Comment: Thanks, and one more thing. Is there any way to know total number of posts. Because I dont know beforehand how many posts does a user have, and I want to fetch all posts of a particular user.

Comment: Try the result paging method mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it :

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import GetPosts
from wordpress_xmlrpc import WordPressTerm
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods import posts


client = Client('site/xmlrpc.php', 'user', 'pass')
data = []
offset = 0
increment = 20
while True:
        wp_posts = client.call(posts.GetPosts({'number': increment, 'offset': offset}))
        if len(wp_posts) == 0:
                break  # no more posts returned
        for post in wp_posts:
                print(post.title)
                data.append(post.title)
        offset = offset + increment
```